# Using std::greater<K> and std::greater_equal<K> in a ternary

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using `std::find_if` and as the third argument I'd like to use a ternary within `std::bind2nd`:

```
std::bind2nd(foo ? std::greater<K>() : std::greater_equal<K>(), bar);
```

for some type `K`. `foo` is a `bool` flag. But this is not syntatically correct since `std::greater<K>()` and `std::greater_equal<K>()` are different types.

Ideally I'd like to remove the ternary (since the above runs in a loop for various `bar`s) and have

```
auto predicate = foo ? std::greater<K>() : std::greater_equal<K>();
std::bind2nd(predicate, bar); /*this statement is in a loop*/
```

But this is not legal either as the type for `predicate` is not known at compile time. But `std::bind2nd` can take either type so my thinking is that there *could* be a way of achieving what I want. Is there?

Comment: Apologies: this is a reworked question. This one, I hope, makes it clear that the first invocation **doesn't** compile either!

Comment: Interesting that you are using C++11 with `bind2nd`, which is *deprecated*.

Comment: Old-fashioned boss. What is the alternative? Or should I ask a new question to ask that?

Comment: @YogiBear `[foo,bar](K const& a) { return foo? (a>bar) : (a>=bar); }`

Comment: ^ Probably a better answer than the type erasure in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MSalters The lambda is nicer to read, but the 'foo check' is supposed to be done outside the loop to increase performance.

Comment: @PaulOmta: Leave that to the compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the operands of the same type:

```
auto predicate = foo
             ? std::function<bool(K,K)>(std::greater<K>())
             : std::function<bool(K,K)>(std::greater_equal<K>());
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/bENRRP)

Rationale:

> **§ 5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond] / p3**
>
> [...] if the second and third operand **have different types** and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class
>   type, or if both are glvalues of the same value category and the same type except for cv-qualification, an
>   attempt is made to convert each of those operands to the type of the other.

There is no conversion between `std::greater<K>()` and `std::greater_equal<K>()` that a compiler could perform on its own.

Comment: gettin' a load of compile errors. Which header is `std::function` in?

Comment: @YogiBear: C++11's `<functional>`

Comment: Got it. +1 great answer! (Now going to read up on std::function).

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on using the ternary operator, you can cast one of the operand to the desired type (here we force a `std::function<bool(const K&, const K&)>`), which will also be the type deduced by `auto`:

```
auto predicate = foo ? std::greater<K>() : (std::function<bool(const K&, const K&)>) std::greater_equal<K>();
```

And a lambda would also do it, possibly more readable (and without the need for `<functional>`) :

```
auto predicate = [&](const K& a) { return foo ? (a > bar) : (a >= bar); };
predicate(val);
```

---

**Notes:**

`bind2nd` is *deprecated* in C++11, you should use `std::bind` instead :

```
std::bind(predicate, bar, std::placeholders::_1);
```

Comment: Your `std::bind` call in the note is the wrong way around - you want the input to be on the left side of the `>` or `>=`.

Answer (score 0):

based on the accepted answer, but I'd invert the order of operations:

```
auto predicate = foo
             ? std::function<bool(K)>(std::bind(std::greater<K>(), bar))
             : std::function<bool(K)>(std::bind(std::greater_equal<K>(), bar));
```

Both `bind` and `function` have some type erasure overhead, and I suspect it's somewhat smaller in this order. That's because the result of `bind` is specified as something that can be stored in a `std::function`, but the other way around is more coincidental.

Comment: In what way does `std::bind` have "type-erasure" overhead? `std::bind` does no erasure whatsoever, the result type is left implementation-defined. It's only required to have an `operator()`, and _anything_ that has that can be stored in a `std::function`.

Comment: @Xeo: Good point. Not only is it implementation-defined, but it appears it can even depend on the bound arguments. (If the type was implementation-defined but independent of the bound arguments, that single type would need type erasure internally)